# Evaluate algorithm accepting a list of arrays on a regular grid

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to `numpy`. I have an algorithm that requires a 2-dimensional array as input returning a 1-dimensional array of length `len(Q)`.

```
def algo(Q):
    assert Q.ndim == 2, 'Wrong dimension'
    # Exposition only. This actually creates a new array and so on.
    return np.linspace(0,10,len(Q))
```

I would usually use this algorithm like this:

```
 x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]) # A list of points.
 algo(x)
```

I would like to evaluate this algorithm on a regular grid. I know how to use `meshgrid` to get a matrix representing the grid:

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
y = np.linspace(0,10,10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

However, I do not know how to combine `X` and `Y` to get a list of `points` suitable as input to my algorithm. Is the approach with `meshgrid` wrong to begin with and should I just create the complete `grid` with straight forward two for-loops?

I cannot change `algo` (which is actually just a wrapper around the [query](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html) member of `scipy.spatial.KDTree`).

Comment: I don't quite understand - what are the numbers in your 2d grid?

Comment: @HenryGomersall Another way to say it is that `algo` accepts an array of length 2 arrays. I come from a world with types everywhere and really have no good other way to say it.

Comment: Right, so `meshgrid` gives you a pair of arrays, one giving the x values, and the other giving the y values, so you need some function that maps from x and y to whatever your values are, e.g. `z = x**2 + y**2` for a 2D parabola. In this case `z` would be your input.

Comment: To be clear, meshgrid is just one tool for generating 2D arrays. If you wanted to create your example array, you'd do best to use a reshape command on a 1d array: `np.arange(1, 7).reshape((3, 2))`.

Comment: Looking at `KDTree`, is your input NxM, where N is the number of locations you wish to query and M is the number of dimensions (2?). So, where are you locations coming from?

Comment: @HenryGomersall Exactly. The locations are generated by me: points on a regular grid. That's why I though `meshgrid` would be the suitable tool for the job and I would use `meshgrid` + `knnsearch` in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given I think I finally understand what you want, you can use `meshgrid` as follows:

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
y = np.linspace(0,10,10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

grid_coords = np.vstack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel())).ravel('F').reshape((-1, 2))
```

The last line is not exactly readable, but is equivalent to

```
grid_coords = np.empty((X.size, 2), X.dtype)
grid_coords[:, 0] = X.ravel()
grid_coords[:, 1] = Y.ravel()
```

To be honest, I'd probably use the second form for readability.

Edit: the use of the `ravel('F')` is a neat trick. It works because `ravel('F')` flattens the output for the input in column major order - when it finds it isn't in column major order, it needs to copy the result to make it so, which interleaves the values, so in row major order, we have what we want.